# I want to update ids in current page codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

i have this following method i want to update the records in the current page..by attendance_id but its updating all the records..how can avoid this

```
 function manage_teacher_attendance_update($timestamp = '')
    {

   $running_year = $this->db->get_where('settings' , array('type' => 'running_year'))->row()->description;
        $active_sms_service = $this->db->get_where('settings' , array('type' => 'active_sms_service'))->row()->description;
        $attendance_of_teachers = $this->db->get_where('teacher_attendance', array('year'=>$running_year,'timestamp' => $timestamp))->result_array();



        foreach($attendance_of_teachers as $row) {
            $attendance_status = $this->input->post('status_'.$row['attendance_id']);
            $leave_status = $this->input->post('leave_status'.$row['attendance_id']);

            $this->db->where('attendance_id' , $row['attendance_id']);
            $this->db->update('teacher_attendance' , array('status' => $attendance_status,'leave_status' => $leave_status));


      }
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message' , get_phrase('attendance_updated'));
        redirect(base_url().'index.php?admin/manage_teacher_attendance_view/'.$timestamp , 'refresh');
    }
```

lets say if i update it few of the selected options and update it..and next time i select some other options and update it..its erasing everything i updated previously

Comment: what do you mean by this `updating all the records`? all records updated in same value or something what?

Comment: I don't now much about CI but could it be that you only have running_year records of one year like 2016 in your database? Because then it will select all records.

Comment: lets say if i update it few of the selected options and update it..and next time i select some other options and update it..its erasing everything i updated previously

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$this->db->flush_cache();
$this->db->where('attendance_id' , $row['attendance_id']);
$this->db->update('teacher_attendance' , array('status' =>       $attendance_status,'leave_status' => $leave_status));
```

it will update all the record for which attendance_id is fetched from above query

Comment: well i dont want to update all the records at once  instead i want to update few at a time

Comment: Which condition to be applied for update few at a time?

Comment: According to your query it will update all the record which has contain given attendance_id in where clause. If you want to update specific record then attendance_id should be the primary key of your respective table.